# Is there any open source OCR plugin for Alfresco

Tags: ocr, alfresco

I am using Alfresco community edition for developing a document management system. Looking for an open source OCR plugin that extracts text out of images and stores against file Metadata.

Answer (score 2):

Searching http://addons.alfresco.com for "OCR" returns this [potential](https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-simple-ocr-action).

You can also just use other open source OCR packages, like [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), and integrate it yourself by writing an extension using Alfresco's Java API.